# discord.py send_message(file=file) throwing an error

Tags: discord.py

I´m trying to make a discord bot using discord.py and I made a command that sends an embed with a file. Every probably second time it throws an error.

Here is the code:

```
@com_tree.command(name="plane", description="Generates a random plane", guild=discord.Object(id=ID))
async def random_plane(interaction):
    plane = random.choice(planes)
    file = discord.File(fp=f"B777.png", filename="image.png")

    embed=discord.Embed(title=plane, url=f"https://www.google.com/search?q={plane}", colour=discord.Colour.from_str("#2FD9FF"))
    embed.set_image(url="attachment://image.png")

    await interaction.response.send_message(file=file, embed=embed)
```

And it throws an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Programming\Projects\Discord bot\bot-env\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 842, in _do_call
    return await self._callback(interaction, **params)  # type: ignore
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Programming\Projects\Discord bot\main.py", line 32, in random_plane
    await interaction.response.send_message(file=file, embed=embed)
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Programming\Projects\Discord bot\bot-env\Lib\site-packages\discord\interactions.py", line 778, in send_message
    await adapter.create_interaction_response(
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Programming\Projects\Discord bot\bot-env\Lib\site-packages\discord\webhook\async_.py", line 219, in request
    raise NotFound(response, data)
discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10062): Unknown interaction

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Programming\Projects\Discord bot\bot-env\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\tree.py", line 1248, in _call
    await command._invoke_with_namespace(interaction, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Programming\Projects\Discord bot\bot-env\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 867, in _invoke_with_namespace    
    return await self._do_call(interaction, transformed_values)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Programming\Projects\Discord bot\bot-env\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 860, in _do_call
    raise CommandInvokeError(self, e) from e
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'plane' raised an exception: NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10062): Unknown interaction
```

I tried removing the file=file from the await interaction.response.send_message(file=file, embed=embed) and it worked perfectly every time, but it obviously didn´t display the image. I don´t know, how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning of your function use

```
await interaction.response.defer()
```

When you're responding, use

```
await interaction.followup.send(...)
```

As previously mentioned you need to respond to an interaction within 3 seconds otherwise it will 404 - meaning that processing the file and uploading it is taking a little too long.

Answer (score 0):

You should respond to an interaction within 3 seconds. Probably your Bot is taking too long to upload the file.

Comment: I reduced the image data size and it works, thanks!

Comment: If you need to upload larger files check @jordan answer